# What is more common pronunciation for 本文?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

What is more common pronunciation for 本文: ほんぶん or ほんもん? Is it geographically specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll use every day for *text body* (main part of text) is ほんぶん. The reading ほんもん is a jargon among historians (inherited more traditional 呉音 pronunciation).

A similar example is 文書. The daily pronunciation is ぶんしょ, which means *document*, while in paleographic context it reads もんじょ, to mean *manuscript* or particularly *epistle*.